# Socket hangs when trying to read input stream from web browser Java

Tags: java, sockets, webclient

I am attempting to read an input stream from a socket provided by a web browser client. Every approach I have taken has got the same results thus far, it just hangs and I don't know why. I have tried `mark()` marking the read limit to what is available and still no go.

```
inputStream.mark(inputStream.available());

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 9];
int read;

while((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

I have also tried `clientSocket.shutdownInput()` to tried to fix this issue, still no good.

Here is my attempt below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ServerSocket server = null;

        try {

            // Server is listening on port 3001
            server = new ServerSocket(3001, 1, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
            server.setReuseAddress(true);

            // running infinite loop for getting
            // client request
            while (true) {

                // socket object to receive incoming client
                // requests
                Socket client = server.accept();

                // Displaying that new client is connected
                // to Server
                System.out.println("New client connected"
                        + client.getInetAddress()
                        .getHostAddress());


                // create a new thread object
                ClientHandler clientSock
                        = new ClientHandler(client);

                // This thread will handle the client
                // separately
                new Thread(clientSock).start();

            }
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // ClientHandler class
    private static class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

        private final Socket clientSocket;

        // Constructor
        public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        public void run() {


            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream clientOutput = null;
            try {

                inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                inputStream.mark(inputStream.available());

                clientSocket.shutdownInput();

                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 9];
                int numRead;

                while((numRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                }

                byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();

                String payloadString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                System.out.println(payloadString);

                clientOutput = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                clientOutput.write(("HTTP/1.1 \r\n" + "200 OK").getBytes());
                clientOutput.write(("ContentType: " + "text/html" + "\r\n").getBytes());
                clientOutput.write("\r\n".getBytes());
                clientOutput.write("Hello World!".getBytes());
                clientOutput.write("\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                clientOutput.flush();
                inputStream.close();
                clientOutput.close();
                try{
                    clientSocket.close();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Did you create the new socket like here
`Socket socket = new Socket("example.com", 1234);`

Comment: @JayamalJayamaha No, I used the ServerSocket to create the new socket per request. `Socket socket = server.accept();`

Comment: Then did you create the server socket like this  `ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1408);`

Comment: @JayamalJayamaha, I just added the rest of the code. I was following a "How to" but they didn't go into detail on how to implement with a browser client. It would be pretty useful I think.

Answer (score 0):

browsers suggests you should toss this all in the garbage and use HTTP, because, well, browsers.

But, if you insist, there are two problems here.

1. You've made it crazy complicated.

You can take all of that code and replace it all with this simple little line:

```
byte[] bytes = in.readAllBytes();
```

That replaces the lines starting with `in.mark(in.available())` (this line does nothing at all, I have no idea where you got this from. If you think it is supposed to do something specific, you might want to mention that. Because it doesn't do anything. `mark` is useful if you ever `reset`, which you aren't, and you don't need to here, hence, useless), all the way to `byte[] bytes =...;

2. sockets don't close unless sender goes out of its way to close it

Your read code (yours, or the much simpler one-liner above) reads everything until the stream closes. In your second snippet, you close it right away, which obviously doesn't work. You **cannot** know when to close it, the **sender** does this job. Evidently it's not doing it.

I advise you to adapt protocols that pre-roll sizes, so you know how much to read and aren't dependent on closing the socket just to signal that the data is sent.

For example:

```
byte[] sizeRaw = in.readNBytes(4);
int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();
byte[] bytes = in.readNBytes(size);
```

You will of course have to adjust the sending code to send the size first (as a 32-bit value, big endian). One way or another you have to look at the sending code here. Either fix it so that it closes once done, or, better yet, adjust it so it sends size first.

Comment: Thank you but forgive me for saying this but I read somewhere that using readAllBytes is dangerous when dealing with large requests like file uploads.. Also, I am trying to stay Java 8 if possible. I will give it a try though, thank you!!!

Comment: The problem with listening to advice like 'it is dangerous' without knowing what or why, is that this virtually never actually gets you anywhere. It is 'dangerous' in that it will throw an OutOfMemoryError if the input is very large. Which your snippet _also_ does. You've spent 10 lines to badly recreate `readAll`, warts and all.